# Laravel4 Composer update failing

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm working on a Laravel 4 project. 
When I try to update my packages with Composer, it gets to doctrine/collections but then throws this error:

```
[Runtime Exception]
Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no

error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

Exception trace: http://pastebin.com/Js3nKrhy

I tried removing the index in doctrine/collections but then I it tells me the format is incorrect in refs/remotes/origin/master.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fix this by removing the index (make a backup before, if you like):

```
$ rm -f .git/index
```

Then, restore your index:

```
$ git reset
```

Comment: I tried this but that's when I get the incorrect format error

Comment: If everything fails, just delete the whole vendor/doctrine/collections folder and do composer update again. it should simply reinstall the package in that case.

Comment: Worked for me, although not the exact same situation; similar error message.