# composer update on mac not working

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Since I updated my PHP version to 5.4, I have trouble to update composer on my symphony 2 project.

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

gives me:

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
_https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no

  error: bad index file sha1 signature
  fatal: index file corrupt
```

Here is link to a screenshot:

http://sanofuzir.com/Screen.jpg

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use code and quote formatting to make your post more readable.

Comment: The diagnostic command is `composer diag`, and it will tell you something about the things that might be wrong. You probably disabled the SSL module with your update.

Comment: try the solution mentioned here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947791/laravel4-composer-update-failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's more likely that you can't even ping the url on the console.
then try the solution here: https://discussions.apple.com/message/10713911#10713911
just refresh your DHCP address, and it works for me!