# composer self-update fails on OSX

Tags: php, macos, openssl, composer-php

On an OSX System, there is XAMPP installed, with PHP 5.6.3.

```
composer self-update
```

and

```
composer update
```

fail with the message:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] 
The "https://getcomposer.org/version"; file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: 
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed 
Failed to enable crypto 
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

There's something wrong with the openssl installation or the certificates.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Quoting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234235/composer-update-on-mac-not-working "The diagnostic command is composer diag, and it will tell you something about the things that might be wrong. You probably disabled the SSL module with your update. –  Sven Oct 7 '13 at 23:15" Try this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest the following steps:

1. enable the OpenSSL extension in `php.ini` - `extension=php_openssl.so`
2. ensure that you have SSL certs configured in `php.ini`

   ```
   curl.cainfo=/full/path/to/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   openssl.cafile=/full/path/to/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   ```

   If certs are missing, download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and rename to ca-bundle.crt

Restart PHP after modifying php.ini and try to run your composer commands again.

Answer (score -5):

Try `sudo composer self-update` that should work.

Comment: There's nothing to do with SUDO.

Comment: You should at least add some explanation to your answer, such that others can learn from it