# composer SSL Err mac os high sierra

Tags: macos, ssl, composer-php

i can't install composer on my computer i am running mac os high sierra.

when i do this commande :

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

i got an error of ssl that says

```
ismails-MacBook-Pro:Desktop ismailtaibi$ php composer-setup.phpAll settings correct for using ComposerDownloading...The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed
Retrying...
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

any solution ?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241939/composer-install-failed?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701431/composer-self-update-fails-on-osx

Comment: Please share more details, like the PHP version you are using, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: php version /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer install failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241939/composer-install-failed)

Answer (score -2):

Fixed By adding these codes in the php.ini file

```
curl.cainfo="C:/wamp/cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:/wamp/cacert.pem"
```

Comment: `C:/wamp` on a Mac system? That works?

Comment: i'm using MAMP. it works for me

Comment: this makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: i added those 2 lines of code and it works for me